# Error 18456 error severity 14 state 5 SQL Server 2012 SCCM2012 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We had a primary site for SCCM 2012 SP1 running fine. I then installed CAS for SCCM on another server. The prerequisites required me to change the collation on the existing server. I did this and ran a rebuild database command at the same time. The SCCM database for the site dropped, along with a reporting database and temp reporting database. I had to re-add some users to the instance and marry up with the reattached databases (the ones that had dropped). I am now getting a SQL Server error as follows:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
>   2013-11-20 16:28:44.73 Logon
>   Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'. Reason: Could not find a
>   login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

SCCM user auto discovery isn't working as new users in AD are not being written into the database, probably due to this. I have recreated the local machine user and checked NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, and DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$ users match between the databases and the server and the SIDs all match. To do this, I used:

```
select * from sys.database_principals
select * from sys.server_principals
```

All connections are local and using windows authentication. The owner of the SCCM database is 'sa' and the SID matches. TCP/IP and named pipes are enabled, the ports for connection are static. The 3 users above are set as sysadmin on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could the `DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$` have been affected by the change in collation?  What was the previous collation, and what is the collation now?  Was anything else changed aside from the collation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember what it was previously. I don't think it was the collation change that broke it, I think it was the rebuilddatabase command that broke it. I think it rebuilt the system databases from the ground up with new collation, I guess resetting security on the way. Problem is, I have no idea what security has changed to cause this problem or how to troubleshoot it. Collation is now SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Thanks

Comment: Collation was a long shot, admittedly, but since you mentioned it I thought I might eliminate that.  I assume you don't have a backup of the old `system.mdf` - that is where the security accounts would be.

Comment: We run a nightly backup of the SQL. I had asked on the SCCM website whether a SQL restore would fix the problem and return the primary site to a state prior to becoming a child site, but no-one got back to me so I thought I would pursue a possible easy fix via permissions, but that doesn't look like it's going to happen either. I assume system.mdf is on the backup as all the databases on that sql are updated, but I'd have to check.

Comment: This [link](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456) could prove useful in resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you did a database rebuild command, do you mean you rebuilt the s[ystem databases for sql server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) & changed the default collation?  Doing this means you've effectively created a new database server.  [I found these instructions for moving the SCCM db from one server to another](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2013/04/02/how-to-move-the-configmgr-2012-site-database-to-a-new-sql-server.aspx).  Looks like they're using a db backup/restore & you've attached the db, but everything else should be the same.  There is a step in the ConfigMgr setup that will fix up the database permissions for you, have you tried that?